# Ruby - substitute \n if not \\n

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to do a regex with lookbehind that changes `\n` to  but **not** if it's a `\\n`.

My closest attempt has no effect:

```
text.gsub /(?<!\\)\n/, ''
```

Unfortunately, no number of backslashes in the lookbehind seem to fix the problem. How can I address this?

Comment: Did you try `/(?<!\\)\\n/` ? (escaping `\ ` before `n`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double the backslash before the `n` in the regex, otherwise it's looking for a newline instead of a literal backslash followed by n:

```
irb(main):001:0> puts "hello\\nthere\\\\n".gsub(/(?<!\\)\\n/, ' ')
hello there\\n
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need anything special. `"\n"` is a single character. It does not include a `"\"` or `"n"` character.

```
text.gsub(/\n/, "")
```

But instead of that, you should do:

```
text.gsub("\n", "")
```

or

```
text.tr("\n", "")
```

But I would do:

```
text.tr($/, "")
```